# “Thanksgiving was in four days”: something sounds funny!

Tags: grammaticality, prepositional-phrases, sequence-of-tenses, copular-verbs, narration

Can you tell me if this sentence is correct? Here it is, in context (bold emphasis added):

> ...mother and sister to let them know she was deploying. **Thanksgiving was in four days**, and Peyton had a feeling she was going to miss it...

I keep thinking that it should be *Thanksgiving was four days away*, or *There were only four days until Thanksgiving*.

I know everyone uses the first version, but I am seeking expert advice.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It isn't very clear what you are asking. As you note, "everyone" uses the first version, so it must be considered grammatical, if less formal than your alternatives, or something like *Thanksgiving was coming in four days*. Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: The English language is tricky. What is and is not grammatical is often a matter of opinion, style, or even convenience.  Then there's the concept of audience. What is appropriate for one audience is not appropriate for another.  So, here's the expert advice you seek. All of the  examples you've given are grammatical. *Was in four days* is perfectly grammatical.  Only you can decide if it's appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not a pre­cise com­par­i­son, but let’s con­sider, for a mo­ment,
the “plu­per­fect” con­struc­tion.

- I **had** taken a shower when the door­bell rang.

Com­pare to the past tense:

- I took a shower.

The “plu­per­fect” is the “past past”, which is to say that you’re
talk­ing about some point in the past, but re­fer­ring to an event
that is even fur­ther in the past.  At the (past tense) mo­ment the
door­bell rang, you *had taken* a shower.  The shower is even fur­ther
into the past than the past to which we’re re­fer­ring.

If I had said *I took a shower when the door­bell rang*, that would
have been a dif­fer­ent state­ment — that the doorbell rang, and then I took a shower.

> Ding Dong!
>
> *turns on shower*

Now, to your ex­am­ple:

- Thanks­giv­ing **was** in four days, and Pey­ton **had** a feel­ing
  she **was** go­ing to miss it.

This is a sim­i­lar con­struc­tion.  You are re­fer­ring to a
spe­cific point in the past, at which Thanks­giv­ing was four days in
the fu­ture.  It’s not four days in the fu­ture *right now*, but it
was at the time to which you are re­fer­ring.  If the “plu­per­fect”
con­struc­tion is the “past past”, this is the “past fu­ture”
con­struc­tion.

If there’s a spe­cific gram­mat­i­cal term for this con­struc­tion, I
don’t know it, but it may be some­thing called the [“past
pro­gres­sive
con­struc­tion”](https://www.thoughtco.com/past-pro%C2%ADgres%C2%ADsive-verbs-1691595).

Comment: @tchrist could you explain your issue with calling pluperfect a "verb tense" rather than "construction" (per your edit)?  This is a grammar school level concept to me. Verb tense: past, present, future, etc.  What am I missing?

Comment: Tense is about morphology of individual words. You can have tensed forms which are finite and untensed ones that are  not finite. When you have a sentence like *I had been calling him for three days before he finally answered me*, both clauses feature verbs inflected into the same tense: *had* is the past tense of *have*, and *answered* is the past tense if *answer*. Nothing else there is a tensed verb inflection. Words like *been* and *calling* are not finite forms. English does not have a pluperfect tense because it has no such inflectional morphology.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically indirect speech and could be rewritten as, "Thanksgiving is in four days and I've a feeling I'm going to miss it," said/thought Peyton. So it's more colloquial than the versions you suggested but is fine here.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, I'd suggest reading the guide for answering. This answer isn't wrong, but it's not the type of answer that typically is sought on this site. We're not a forum. Rather, we're a question and detailed answer site. Please read the guide, and revise your answer.